# Scintilla Text Changed

Tags: c#, wpf, scintilla

I am using Scintilla Text Editor in my WPF application, I would like to enable the user to edit only whitespaces: insert, delete, replace etc.
I want to handle the before text insert event, and before text delete event of the scintilla, but there is no `e.Handled = true` to the `TextModifiedEventArgs`... how can I prevent the insertion / deletion? The `KeyDown` isn't enough for me because it does not always represent the text changed.... 
I have tried the following code:

```
  static void scintilla_BeforeTextModified(object sender, TextModifiedEventArgs e)
    {
        var scintilla = (Scintilla) sender;
        if (scintilla != null)
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(scintilla.Selection.Text) || !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(e.Text))
            {
                // flag to ignore the change
                _ignoreTextChanges = true;
                // save text before modified
                _text = scintilla.Text;                  
            }  }

        }   private void _scintilla_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!_suspendTextChanges)
        {
            _suspendTextChanges = true;
            if (_ignoreTextChanges)
            {
                _ignoreTextChanges = false;
                Text = _text;

                _scintilla.Text = _text;
            }
            else
            {
                Text = _scintilla.Text;
            }
            _suspendTextChanges = false;
        }
        _ignoreTextChanges = false;
    }
```

But the text that I set does not change in scintilla...
Can anyone help me?

Thanks...